# Create UILable at runtime and set autolayout programatically related to each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` in `UITableViewCell`. I am getting a array of names from service and I want to create a `UILabel` in a `for` loop inside a `UIView` which is in `UITableViewCell` according to the text width.

I have done this at my end but the problem is that I want to check if the label which is being created is having a width greater than the space remaining in its superview, then it should be created below the first line just like word wrapping of text in `UILabel`.

What I have done is, I have created a sample of code

```
-(void)addADaynamicViw
{
     [self.vwContainer setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
    UILabel *lblPrevious;
    int totalWidth;
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        //[lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 50)];
        [lbl setNumberOfLines:0];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [lbl setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
        [lbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label Num %d",i]];

        [self.vwContainer addSubview:lbl];

        NSLayoutConstraint *top;
        top=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.vwContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

        NSLayoutConstraint  *left;
        if (lblPrevious) {
            CGSize size = lblPrevious.intrinsicContentSize;
            NSLog(@"intrinzik content size =%f",size.width);
         left =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:lblPrevious attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:size.width+2];
        }
       else
       {

        left=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.vwContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:0];
       }

        NSLayoutConstraint *width=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:10];


        NSLayoutConstraint *height=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:50];

         NSLayoutConstraint *bottom=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.vwContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

        NSLayoutConstraint *right=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:lbl attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:self.vwContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0];



        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:left];
        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:bottom];
        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:width];
        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:top];
        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:height];
        [self.vwContainer addConstraint:right];
        lblPrevious=lbl;
        CGSize size = lblPrevious.intrinsicContentSize;
        totalWidth+=size.width;
    }


    [self.vwContainer layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.vwContainer updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

}
```

This line of code is creating the label programmatically after the end of previous label, but I want that if the label which is being created does not fit in its superview then it should increase the height of its superview and should start from 0 of its superview, but below the first label.

[image: In this image we can see labels are created programmatically and is after the previous label, but the problem is in the last, it is showing seventh just above 5th and 6th label, I want to show 5th 6th and 7th label from the next line]

[image: I have added this constraints to vwContainer]

Comment: What constraints have you added to the vwContainer object?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the screen shot of vwContainer constraints.

Comment: Just asking. Why don't use collection view ?

Comment: I am going to use this feature in uitablviewcell . if i will use collection view for this purpose then a collectionview will be created in each cell which is not a good idea.

Comment: If you don't want to use a collection view (remembering that you will only have a collection view for each *visible* cell, not each cell) then I would suggest at least creating a UIView subclass so that you can abstract the layout from your table cell and take advantage of being able to set `intrinisicContentSize` so that you don't need to anything to have the auto resting capability